# Bash delete/modify line from a file

Tags: bash

Lets say I have a file contacts.txt in this format

```
number1:name1:phone1:adress1
number2:name2:phone2:adress2
```

The question is how can I delete a line(contact) from that file or modify any of the components of the contact?
To delete a line I thought of using this

```
grep -ve "name1"
```

and overwrite the entire file but Im sure there is a better way to do this...

Comment: sed would be a useful tool to solve this  As a starting point for a cookbook approach see http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Comment: I was answering your recently deleted question when you deleted it: You're describing the behavior of a dialog window, not an application window -- so make it one by creating and showing a JDialog, not a JFrame. One quick way is to use a JOptionPane and have it show your GUI held by a JPanel. This GUI can be as complex as need be. Another  is to create and display a modal JDialog....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data appears to be colon-delimited, the most obvious tool to handle it is awk.

Simple sed approaches have the disadvantage that they treat the input as plain text, which does not always yield the desired result. If, for example, you have a Mr. Smith and a Mrs. Doolittle who lives in Smithy Place 23, removing all lines that contain "Smith" will remove Mrs. Doolittle along with Mr. Smith.

awk, on the other hand, splits the line into fields so that you can easily do tests on those fields individually. For example, to remove Mr. Smith from the file, you would use

```
awk -F : '$2 != "Smith"' myfile.txt
```

Where `$2` stands for the second field, making this call select all lines whose second field is "Smith". `-F :` sets the input field separator to a colon rather than the default whitespace, so that the lines in the file are split at colons.

It also allows straightforward modification. To register Mr. Smith's new phone number, for example, you might use

```
awk -F : 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 == "Smith" { $3 = "555-123456" } { print }' myfile.txt
```

Here `OFS` is the output field separator; we set it to the same as the input field separator in the beginning so that the output is just as colon-delimited as the input. The rest should be fairly self-explanatory -- if the second field is "Smith", the third is set to "555-123456", and regardless of whether the transformation happened (because there is no attached condition), the line is printed<sup>1</sup>.

For in-place editing, you will need GNU awk 4.1.0 or later (add the `-i inplace` option to the call), but since it is generally desirable to have a backup in case things go wrong, I'd just use

```
cp myfile.txt myfile.txt~
awk ... myfile.txt~ > myfile.txt
```

or so.

You can find a very useful awk tutorial [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

<sup>1</sup> Actually, instead of `{ print }` it is more common to write the shorter `1` (which, as a non-zero value, means true when treated as a condition). How this works is explained in the tutorial; in short: An action without a condition is executed unconditionally, and a condition without an action performs the default action (printing) if the condition is true. I put in `{ print }` because it is less confusing to the beginner's eye.

Answer (score 1):

To do inline changes in myfile.txt for e.g.

```
sed -i.bak '/name1/d' myfile.txt
```

Will do inplace change in myfile.txt by deleting line containing name1 while before modifying file, it will create myfile.txt.bak with original content.

If you want to modify the line, so something like:

```
sed -i.bak 's/name1/name2/g' myfile.txt
```

This will search for name1 and replace it with name2 in the line.

Comment: The `.bak` creates a backup file of the original with the name `original.bak`. To omit creating a backup, just use `sed -i ...`.